# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar el diccionario de cumpleaños?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

espero se encuentren muy bien.
Quiero ordenar un diccionario (dentro de una función) en orden ascendente con respecto al año de nacimiento. He aplicado el método `sorted()` habiendo hecho ya `import operator`. Pero no logro imprimir el diccionario como quiero. He intentado esto:

```
cumples={}
def Cumple_s():
    times = int(input('¿Cuantos vas a agregar? '))
    print()
    for i in range(0, times):
        name = input('Dame el nombre: ')
        day = input('Dame el día: ')
        mon = input('Dame el mes: ')
        year = input('Dame el año: ')
        print()
        lt = cumples.get(year,[])
        lt.append((name,mon,day))
        cumples[year] = lt
    cumples_ord = {k: v for k, v in sorted(cumples.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])}
print(cumples_ord)
```

Un ejemplo **output** de que busco es:

```
{'1996': [('Luis', 'Agosto', '15')], '1995': [('Ana', 'Agosto', '25')], '1994': [('Karla', 'Marzo', '27')] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido UPi c:

Logré lo que buscas. No puedes imprimirlo por que el diccionario lo creaste en una variable local. Eso significa que solo es accesible dentro de la función y se borra al terminar de ejecutarse.
Puedes crearla afuera usando `global`

Además hice una pequeña modificación en donde ordenas el diccionario para que sea acorde a tu output.
Aquí abajo te dejo el código:

```
cumples={}
def Cumple_s():
    global cumples_ord
    
    times = int(input('¿Cuantos vas a agregar? '))
    print()
    for i in range(0, times):
        name = input('Dame el nombre: ')
        day = input('Dame el día: ')
        mon = input('Dame el mes: ')
        year = input('Dame el año: ')
        print()
        lt = cumples.get(year,[])
        lt.append((name,mon,day))
        cumples[year] = lt
    cumples_ord = dict(sorted(cumples.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True))

Cumple_s()
print(cumples_ord)
```

También puedes usar `return` para que la función devuelva el diccionario. Es mejor hacer esto ultimo en mi opinion.

```
cumples={}
def Cumple_s():
    times = int(input('¿Cuantos vas a agregar? '))
    print()
    for i in range(0, times):
        name = input('Dame el nombre: ')
        day = input('Dame el día: ')
        mon = input('Dame el mes: ')
        year = input('Dame el año: ')
        print()
        lt = cumples.get(year,[])
        lt.append((name,mon,day))
        cumples[year] = lt

    return dict(sorted(cumples.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True))

cumples_ord=Cumple_s()
print(cumples_ord)
```

Comment: Fua! Muchísimas gracias, Dante!

Comment: De nada! Ibas en buen camino con tu forma de ordenar el diccionario!